# Frege putStr flushing behavior is different from Haskell or Java

Tags: frege

Suppose you prompt for user input with a combination of `putStr` and `getLine`:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "A line with line termination" -- printed correctly
    putStr   "A line without line termination, e.g. to prompt for input: " -- NOT printed
    line <-  getLine
    putStrLn ("You entered: " ++ line)
```

In contrast to Haskell, Frege does not print the 2nd line (which uses `putStr` rather than `putStrLn`). Is this behavior of a missing flush intended?

If Frege deviates from Haskell behavior, I would assume it to mimic Java's behavior instead. A conceptually similar example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("A line with line termination");
    System.out.print("A line without line termination, e.g. to prompt for input: ");
    String line = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    System.out.println("You entered: " + line);
}
```

This however behaves like the Haskell variant, i.e. `System.out.print` gets flushed immediately.

Thanks in advance for any feedback!

PS: The (mis?)behavior can be reproduced with the latest Eclipse-Plugin as well as IntelliJ/Gradle.

Comment: Are you sure that you have used the same JRE for both the Java and the Frege variant?

Comment: Yep, I'm actually running both from the same Eclipse project (with jdk1.8.0_05)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Java code uses System.out, which is a PrintStream.
The Frege code uses a PrintWriter.

These two classes work a bit differently with respect to flushing. From the docs of PrintWriter:

> Unlike the {@link PrintStream} class, if automatic flushing is enabled
>   it will be done only when one of the println, printf, or format methods is invoked, ..

So for your Frege code, you have to add a `stdout.flush` after the `print` to make it appear immediately.

Feel free to file an issue with the request to align Frege with the Haskell behavior in this regard. (We could leave the `print` as is but make the `putStr` add the `flush` automatically.)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I would definitely prefer "auto-flush" for `putStr`. Why would you leave `print` as is? IIRC, `print` also flushes in Haskell...

Comment: Turns out Haskell's behavior is controlled by a [BufferMode](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-IO.html#t:BufferMode). `hGetBuffering stdout >>= print` defaults to `NoBuffering` on my OSX machine (that's why it behaved differently compared to Frege) but this default is implementation-specific. No longer sure whether I should file an issue or just live with `stdout.flush` :-)

Comment: @netzwerg this is one of the subtle points where the POSIXish behaviour of the Haskell RTS is not 100% mirrored by the JRE. Arguably, you can be expected to flush your output stream, writer, handle, channel or whatever when you want an incomplete line  to get printed.

Comment: Tx, @Ingo, I can totally live with the manual flush now that I understand its background